# Is there any elegant way of excluding form element from the `values` array of the `FormState`?

Tags: 8, forms

I know that the `values` array can be cleaned up in the validation or submit callback, but can we somehow mark the element itself to be not put in the `values` array of the `FormState`?

Answer (score 1):

Not within the building of the form as far as I know. You'd need to strip out the values you don't want in the submit handler as you mentioned.

This is probably the easiest way to remove the default form values:

```
$values = $form_state->cleanValues()->getValues();
```

That will remove: form_id, form_token, form_build_id, op